# How are the parameters $\alpha_i$ of hard attention trained?

Tags: computer-vision, training, papers, attention

I have a question about [Show, Attend and Tell: Neural Image CaptionGeneration with Visual Attention](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/xuc15.pdf) paper by Xu. The basic mechanism of stochastic hard attention is that each pixel of the input image has a corresponding parameter $\alpha_i$, which describes the probability that this pixel will be chosen for further processing.

But I don't see an explanation of how to train or define this parameter in the paper. Can someone explain how to train this $\alpha_i$ for each pixel?